# Storing values that aren't defined in the schema (dynamic schema?)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have a Schema definition

```
var Users = mongoose.model('Users', new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    salt: String,
    hash: String,
    facebook: {
        id: String
        }
    }));
```

But I want to later

```
user = new Users({
    username: 'myusername',
    facebook: {
        id: '3141592653',
        displayName: 'mydisplayname'   // <- wasn't in the schema ^
    }
});
```

Then `displayName` simply doesn't gets stored. Is this not allowed in mongoose? Because I would imagine since MongoDB is "schema-less" there ought to be a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the [`strict`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) option on the schema to allow fields not in the schema to be saved:

```js
var Users = mongoose.model('Users', new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    salt: String,
    hash: String,
    facebook: {
        id: String
    }
}, { strict: false }));
```